# How to select radio button in pdf form using PyPDF2?

Tags: python, pypdf

After reading the PDF form my radio button fields look like this

```
'Are you ok': {
    '/FT': '/Btn',
    '/Kids': [
      IndirectObject(72,
      0),
      IndirectObject(80,
      0)
    ],
    '/T': 'Are you ok',
    '/TU': 'Are you ok',
    '/Ff': 49152
  }
```

There are two options, yes or no.  I am using PyPDF2 but I can't select any of the buttons programmatically. I have done so for the checkbox and textfields.

Comment: Change the `0` in the `IndirectObject`s to `1`? (Just a guess)

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have an example PDF so that people can help you?